# Left click then right click is treated as double click in Mac QGIS Layers

Tags: qgis

I am having an issue with QGIS 1.8.0 on my Mac where I left click then right click which gets treated as a double click if the timing is too close together and brings up the Layer Properties box.

This usually happens when I am focused on a different program, left click to gain QGIS' focus and then right click to get a context menu for a layer. This is force of habit I guess.

1. Is there a way to disable the Layer Properties from appearing with a
   double click? I know that you can choose between the Attribute Table
   and the Properties Box.
2. Should this issue be added as a bug report to QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has bothered me for a while, too! (I guess we have the same habits :^)

It also happened whenever the legend was out of focus while still in QGIS (like when editing in the canvas, then doing a quick left-right click in the legend). I have [fixed this in master branch](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/commit/52e6c50b2cb5a7a868ea03d2bceb298e511a0db1), but just for Mac since @underdark indicated it did not exhibit the same behavior under Linux.

Now on Mac, any quick left-right clicks on legend items shows the contextual menu for that item, as expected.

There will be no backporting of fixes in master branch to 1.8. If you wish to take advantage of the fix, try [compiling QGIS yourself](https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/blob/master/INSTALL#L1155), or possibly [try one of the nightly builds](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#421-Nightly-Builds) in a day or so.

In the future I suggest reporting any bugs to the [issue tracker at hub.qgis.org](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues) for more direct communication with developers.

Comment: Thanks @dakcarto I will try one of the nightly builds in a few days. I will also use the issue tracker in the future. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a feature request for adding another option to the double-click settings for "do nothing".

This behavior seems to be a specialty of your OS. I tried on Ubuntu and no matter how fast I click, there are no double-clicks registered when clicking left and right.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a Mac-problem... I can reproduce the Problem on my MBA.

Is your double-click speed set on the highest setting? If not, try that. I had a way harder time opening the layer preferences with right then left clicking while it was set on the fastest setting.